Function defined on elementary tensors
I'm trying to prove that given two $R$-algebras $A, S$ and an $S$-algebra $X$, and given $g: A \to X$ morphism of $R$-algebras, then the application $f: A\otimes_R S \to X$ defined on elementary tensors as $f(a\otimes s)=g(a)\cdot s$ and extended to $A\otimes_ R S$ by linearity is well defined. This question came to me trying to prove that extension of scalars is left adjoint to the restriction of scalars.
I've tried the following:
considering $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2\in A$ and $s_1,s_2,t_1,t_2\in B$ such that $a_1\otimes s_1+a_2\otimes s_2=b_1\otimes t_1+b_2 \otimes t_2$, we want to prove that
$$
g(a_1)\otimes s_1+g(a_2)\otimes s_2=g(b_1)\otimes t_1+g(b_2) \otimes t_2
$$
We have, adding and subtracting the same quantity:
$$
g(a_1)\otimes s_1+g(a_2)\otimes s_2=g(a_1)\otimes s_1+g(a_1)\otimes s_2-g(a_1)\otimes s_2+g(a_2)\otimes s_2=g(a_1)\otimes(s_1+s_2)+g(a_2-a_1)\otimes s_2=\\ =g(a_1)\otimes(s_1+s_2)+g(a_2)\otimes (s_1+s_2)-g(a_2)\otimes (s_1+s_2)+g(a_2-a_1)\otimes s_2=\\=g(a_1+a_2)\otimes(s_1+s_2)-g(a_2)\otimes (s_1+s_2)+g(a_2-a_1)\otimes s_2=\\
=g(a_1+a_2)\otimes(s_1+s_2)-g(a_1-a_2)\otimes (-s_1+s_2)+g(a_1-a_2)\otimes (-s_1+s_2)-g(a_2)\otimes (s_1+s_2)+g(a_2-a_1)\otimes s_2=\\
=2\cdot g(a_1\otimes s_1+a_2\otimes s_2)+g(a_1-a_2)\otimes (-s_1+s_2)-g(a_2)\otimes (s_1+s_2)+g(a_2-a_1)\otimes s_2
$$
I think I'm supposing that the characteristic is different from 2, and it shouldn't be necessary. Furthermore I don't know how to proceed because I can't cancel out every term besides from the first one, which is equal to $g(b_1\otimes t_1+b_2 \otimes t_2)$, that is what I need alone.
Thank you.

What is your definition of $A\otimes_RS$? The fact that something is a tensor product is usually given by exactly what you're asking for by definition.

I assume your rings are commutative. Since $S$ is an $R$-algebra, you're implicitly given a ring homomorphism $R\to S$, so any $S$-module is also an $R$-module via restriction.
The fact you need is: Give $R$-modules $M,N,T$, any bilinear map $f:M\times N\to T$ induces a unique well-defined linear map $\tilde{f}:M\otimes_RN\to T$. Here, $\tilde f$ is determined by $\tilde f(m\otimes n)=f(m,n)$.
Consider $f:A\times S\to X$ defined by $f(a,s)=g(a)\cdot s$. Check that $f$ is $R$-bilinear (this is easy). Hence, $f$ induces a well defined map $\tilde f$ that acts on elementary tensors in the same way as you described. Finally it remains to check that $\tilde f$ is $S$-linear, but this follows from the definition and I'll leave to you as an exercise.
